# preloading fonts in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know I can preload fonts with `<link rel="preload">`. Problem is, my font file is quite large, so preloading them (with no cache) might take a while and affect FCP. Then I tried dynamically adding CSS font-face after onload for a better FCP score, but that introduced FOUT (a refresh of all text as font was changed).

I'm thinking if it's possible to first download the font without rendering it, the next time user refresh the page, it gets fetched from cache and rendered. It's ok for the page to not use the font for the first time, but later requests should all render my font instantly from cache. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your [font-display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) set to? Because what you describe seems like a good use case for `font-display: fallback;` or `font-display: optional;`

Comment: That's something new to me, never set that, I guess it's auto(default)

Comment: You can use localStorage and this converter to convert font to base64: https://jaicab.com/localFont/